Launching Thunar from Terminal error
I'm running Artix Linux (nonSystemD init runit)
When I go to launch Thunar from the terminal - I get this error message (as of today)
thunar
(thunar:30519): dbind-WARNING **: 17:06:17.012: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/979/at-spi/bus_0: Permission denied
(thunar:30519): thunar-WARNING **: 17:06:17.155: Name 'org.freedesktop.FileManager1' lost on the message dbus.
Trying to launch Caja (from Mate desktop gives me similar errors)
Any idea how to fix?
